How to update Flutter riverpod to version >= 2 (using riverpod decorator)
I have a flutter app and I am using flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1 ... And my code is:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class PersonState {
  int age;
  String? name

  PersonState({
    this.age = 0,
    this.name,
  });
}

class PersonNotifier extends StateNotifier<PersonState> {
  PersonNotifier() : super(PersonState());

  void setAge(int newAge) {
    state = PersonState(
      age: newAge,
      name: state.name,
    );
  }

  void setName(String newName) {
    state = PersonState(
      age: state.age,
      name: newName,
    );
  }

  void clear() {
    state = PersonState();
  }
}

final personProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<PersonNotifier, PersonState>(
  (ref) => PersonNotifier(),
);

I want to update to new flutter_riverpod versions using decorator @riverpod and new concepts. I couldn't find anywhere, how can I do it?

StateNotifier is now marked as legacy.  You'll probably want to migrate that to a Notifier/NotifierProvider.  And you don't need to use generation for something this simple, but you can if you choose.
